# Aggregate Sum total of items from the same date after using a formula to Populate on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have used the formula "IFERROR" to populate data from a couple different sheets into a sperate sheet for reference. I have done that same formula for both the amount sold and the date sold. I want to add up the amount sold on the same date by using a formula so it will populate on its own without my intervention.

for examples
D4-D5 are both 10/26/2023
D4 I sold 120 sheet and D5 I sold 320 sheets. I want to find a formula to calculate that to 440 without compromising the formula I've already set in place on D3.

I hope this example help to figure out what I'm asking because I'm not even sure that it's possible

I plan on using this same formula across several sheets so I don't want to have to keep up with it.

Here is the link for the the Google sheets in Question on sheet "PCB4819" on the far right.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM5J2ZoopJGyxsAjZYGINlk9zZBicMnwYfI2HAeem2A/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried using the same formula that I have already used "IFERROR" to try and narrow that down. I have looked into using the "Query" formula but I am not skilled enough at formulas to figure that out. I've also tried the "filter" Formula but that didn't work either. The "SUM" formula can do what I need it to but its not something this will auto populate as I continue to sure the sheets. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=query(Sold!A:G,"Select G,sum(E) Where A='"&Items!A15&"' group by G label G '',sum(E) ''")
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you so much. I'm going to try and duplicate this across my other items and see if I can figure that out lol! Again I really appreciate the help!